# Joining multiple tables in one

Tags: mysql

I'm revising my previous scenario, I want to know the serial details placed in SALES ORDER versus serial details order filled in DELIVERY RECEIPTS if its correct. There are three tables below, (1)TABLE A - this is my current output upon executing the script below. (2) TABLE B - another table that I want to join (TABLE B) because of serial details. (3) TABLE DESIRED output - i want to achive.. considering : 
if basetype = 17 then it should insert serial in another column (SO_SERIAL)
and if basetype =15 then it should insert serial details in another coloumn (DR_SERIAL). 
By means of this, I was able to analyze that serial used in SO is different/same as used in DR.

Thanks for your help.

```
select a.CardCode 'BPNAME', c.itemcode, a.DocEntry 'SO_DOCENTRY', a.DocNum 'SO Num', c.ObjType'SO_Btype',
b.docEntry 'DR_DOCENTRY',b.BaseRef 'DR_num',b.ObjType 'dr_type'
from ORDR a 
LEFT join dln1 b on a.docentry = b.baseentry 
left join RDR1 c on a.DocEntry = c.DocEntry
```

Table A.

```
BP      ITEMCODE   SO_DOCENTRY   SO_NUM    SO_BTYPE    DR_DOCENTRY    DR_NUM   DR_TYPE
======================================================================================
CITALI  TYB20001M   144900       20152733    17         130775    20152733     15
```

Table B.

```
SERIAL               ITEMCODE     BASEENTRY   BASENUM  BASETYPE  QUANTITY    CARDCODE
=====================================================================================
MCWF-12001-20120601  TYB20001M    144900      20152733  17        10.000000   CITALI    
MBAL-13001-20130101  TYB20001M    130775      103073    15        5.000000    CITALI
```

Desired Output:

```
BP      ITEMCODE   SO_NUM    SO_BTYPE   SO_SERIAL            DR_NUM   DR_TYPE     DR_SERIAL
============================================================================================
CITALI  TYB20001M  20152733   17         MCWF-12001-20120601  20152733  15    AL-13001-20130101
```

Comment: you will use join (maybe on `itemcode` ?)

Comment: Sorry, im a newbie in here and in sql. If i join this with itemcode .. it'll create 2rows. I only want one row as illustrated in mhy desired output.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By means of this, I was able to analyze that serial used in SO is different/same as used in DR.

To match so entries with dr entries you can join table b twice, first time take 'so' entries then second time take 'dr' entries. So you will get "header", "SoEntry", "DrEntry". Then you can compare them. Take this example

```
select t1.BP, t1.ITEMCODE, t21.Serial as SO_SERIAL, t22.SERIAL as DR_Serial
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t21 on t21.ITEMCODE=t1.ITEMCODE and t21.BASETYPE=17
LEFT JOIN table2 t22 on t22.ITEMCODE=t1.ITEMCODE and t22.BASETYPE=15
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but will it work if let say. looking at the above table, if my basetype = 17 (table B) it should insert a value in SO_SERIAL column (desired output) as well as insert a value in DR_serial column once basetype = 15 considering that the BP = cardcode and itemcode (desired output) = itemcode (tableB)

Comment: You can use two joins here.

select a.BP, b1.SERIAL as SO_SERIAL, b2.SERIAL as DR_SERIAL
from tableA a
left join tableB b1 on a.BP=b1.CARDCODE and b1.BASETYPE =a.SO_BTYPE
left join tableB b2 on a.BP=b2.CARDCODE and b2.BASETYPE=a.DR_TYPE;

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn basic joins.
**Definitely you will have to join these two table.**
Here is a good link from where you can start with
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877720/the-best-tutorial-on-joins-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. you need to join over `itemcode` and `BASETYPE`. 
so try this:

```
select A.BP
     , A.ITEMCODE
     , A.SO_NUM
     , A.SO_BTYPE
     , B.serial as SO_SERIAL
     , A.DR_NUM
     , A.DR_TYPE
     , A.DR_SERIAL
from a 
join b on a.itemcode = b.itemcode and a.so_btype = b.basetype
```

Comment: this is my exact query - (if i execute this it will give TABLE A)
select a.CardCode 'BPNAME', c.itemcode, c.Dscription,a.DocEntry, a.DocNum 'SO#',c.ObjType'SOtype',
b.docEntry,b.BaseRef 'DR#',b.ObjType 'drtype',b.Quantity  'drqty'
from ORDR a 
LEFT join dln1 b on a.docentry = b.baseentry 
left join RDR1 c on a.DocEntry = c.DocEntry

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean now. In your main question you said you have two tables and you need a result as described in the third table, now you give a query with three tables and two joins. Sorry, but you should specify your question better, otherwise it's impossible to help you..

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I edited my previously posted question. sorry for confusion.